# commandButton action="#{bean.delete(row)}" in datatable seems to pass wrong row

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable that is initially populated with no data (an empty list). There is a `commandButton` in the footer of the table that adds rows to the table. When a row is added, the last cell in the row is another `commandButton` to delete the row. My issue is that the delete button keeps deleting the first row in the table regardless of which row is selected.

Example: if I add 3 rows to the table and hit the delete button in the last cell of the second row, `action="#{addAccountBean.deleteFixVendor(dataItem)}"` passes the first row to the `deleteFixVendor` method instead of the second row which was clicked. I can't figure out why the object for the first row keeps on getting passed to the delete method regardless of which row button is clicked.

My JSF code:

```
<h:form>
<f:validateBean disabled="#{!empty param['disableValidation']}" >
<p:panel id="panel" header="Add New Account"  > 
    <p:dataTable var="dataItem" value="#{addAccountBean.account.vendors}" >

        <p:column headerText="Vendor"  >                                
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{dataItem.vendor}">                
                        <f:selectItems value="#{addAccountBean.menu.fixOption}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Monthly Cost"  >
                <p:inputText value="#{dataItem.cost}" />    
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Cost Date"  >
                <p:calendar value="#{dataItem.CDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" navigator="true" /> 
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Delete" >
            <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{addAccountBean.deleteFixVendor(dataItem)}" >
                <f:param name="disableValidation" value="true" />
            </h:commandButton>  
        </p:column> 

        <f:facet name="footer" >
            <h:commandButton value="Add New Vendor" action="#{addAccountBean.addFixVendor}" >
                <f:param name="disableValidation" value="true" />
            </h:commandButton>      
        </f:facet>

    </p:dataTable>          
</p:panel>  
</f:validateBean>
</h:form>
```

Bean code:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AddAccountBean implements Serializable {

private AccountData account = new AccountData();

public String addFixVendor() {

    account.getVendors().add(new VendorData());                 
    return "";
}

public String deleteFixVendor(VendorData vData) {

    account.getVendors().remove(vData);                         
    return "";                                                          
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Did you conclude it based on observing or debugging? Did you put a breakpoint on `deleteFixVendor()` method and inspect the passed-in `vData` instance? Or was you merely observing the end result and assumed that the passed-in `vData` instance "would" be the first row? It's namely more likely that this problem is caused by a broken `equals()` method in `VendorData` class than by JSF/EL itself.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC. It was a result of a broken `equals()` method in the `VendorData` class. It is now working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted so far looks fine. The only feasible explanation for this problem is a broken `equals()` method in the `VendorData` class. The [`Collection#remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) will remove the first item in the collection which `equals()` the given object.

Provided that your (base) entity has an `id` property, then this should do:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other != null && getClass() == other.getClass() && id != null)
        ? id.equals(((VendorData) other).id)
        : (other == this);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (id != null) 
        ? (getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode())
        : super.hashCode();
}
```