# ui repeat to show one more value and method is not invoking in managed Bean in JSF2.2

Tags: jsf-2.2

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.bean.foo.foo1}" var="test" varStatus="test1">
    <h:outputText value="#{test.prime}" title="#{test.primeNumber}" />
    <h:outputText value="," rendered="#{!test1.last}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

I am getting a value `example1,example2`

Now after adding a new line:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.bean.foo.foo1}" var="test" varStatus="test1">
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.bean.testNo(test)}" rendered="#{test1.first}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{test.prime}" title="#{test.primeNumber}" />
    <h:outputText value="," rendered="#{!test1.last}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

I want my output something like this  `Hello-  example1,example2......`

But I am  not able to get this output. In fact `testNo(test)` method is not invoked. What exactly is getting wrong over here. Thank you in advance

```
Manage bean method
 private String testNo(Test test) {
        List<Test11> type = Lists.newArrayList();
        String some = someService.findTestNumber(test.getSomeNumber());
        return some;

    }
```

Comment: I can see no reason why it wouldn't work, but I'm not sure why you would need to pass test to `testNo(test)`. Perhaps `testNo(String test)` doesn't exist?

Comment: @Nicholas I have upated my code by passing test i want to retrive some date from database..

Comment: Why not just expose Test as a field in your page bean? `Test` already has a `someNumber` field. Then you would add `value="#{cc.attrs.bean.test.someNumber}"`

Comment: @Nicholas I just want " someNumber" for the query puprpose.I am new to JSF2.2.How will I pass the var=TEST value in to manged bean.Actual there are list of objects which i want to pass in to managed bean and on that list of object I have to find some value from data base..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a basic MVC webapp. There are many tutorials about this, but example always helps: Your model is simple, two entities for a `CompletedTest`:

```
@Entity
public class CompletedTest {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<TestResult> results;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and a `TestResult`:

```
@Entity
public class TestResult {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String result;
    // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Access your `model` through a `service layer`

```
@Stateless
public class TestService {
    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public CompletedTest findTestResultByName(String name) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<CompletedTest> q = cb.createQuery(CompletedTest.class);
        Root<CompletedTest> tr = q.from(CompletedTest.class);
        q.select(tr).where(cb.equal(tr.get("name"), name));
        List<CompletedTest> testResults = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
        if ( testResults.size() > 0 ) return testResults.get(0);
        else return null;
    }
```

The create a `controller` to interface to your `view`:

```
@Model
public class TestResultController {
    @Inject
    private TestService testResultService;

    private CompletedTest testResult;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        testResult = testResultService.findTestResultByName("Test #1");
    }
```

and finally your view is your `JSF` page:

```
<ui:repeat var="r" value="#{testResultController.testResult.results}" varStatus="tSt">
    <h:outputText value="#{testResultController.testResult.name}: " rendered="#{tSt.first}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{r.result}"/>
    <h:outputText value=", " rendered="#{!tSt.last}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

As you can see, the JSF page accesses the `Controller` bean. In that bean is a `PostConstruct` annotation, which gets executed when the JSF page references the bean. The `PostConstruct` executes any code you need to initialize the bean, in this case a call to the `service layer` which loads a test result from the database. Of course, there is a bit of code I didn't include, such as creating a test or showing a list of `CompletedTests` so the user can choose which one he or she wants. You can do all that on a single page with a form and a drop-down list. Further, calling to the database every time the JSF page is loaded will result in poor performance, so there are more sophisticated mechanisms for caching `Entities` in memory, but that is beyond this simple answer.